# Getting unknown local action type in Vuex Store

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have broken up my Vuex store into namespaced modules.

I have created a `User` module, where I need to call my `Showrooms` module. The interesting thing, is that this `action` works fine. But I am updating the store:

```
dispatch('showrooms/updateLocalShowroom',
  {
    weddingId: element.wedding.id,
    showroomDresses: element.showroom.showroomDresses,
    status: element.showroom.status,
    uuid: element.showroom.uuid,
  }, 
    { 
      root: true 
    }
 )
```

But when I try and reset the `Showrooms` store with this:
`dispatch('showrooms/resetShowrooms', { root: true })`

I get the following error:

`[vuex] unknown local action type: showrooms/resetShowrooms, global type: user/showrooms/resetShowrooms`

The only thing I can think of is something is that when I `resetShowrooms` I do it like this in my store module:

This action:

```
resetShowrooms: ({ commit }) => {
  commit('zeroOutShowrooms')
},
```

Calls this mutation

```
zeroOutShowrooms: (state) => {
  Vue.set(state, 'showrooms', [])
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It ends up that `dispatch` is looking for some data in the second position. That's why this was NOT working:

```
resetShowrooms: ({ commit }) => {
  commit('zeroOutShowrooms')
},
```

While this DID work and solved my issue:

```
dispatch('showrooms/resetShowrooms', '', { root: true })
```

Just sending the empty string did the trick and all is good now.